# Compress or Zip a File - Windows Phone Universal Apps - C#

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, zip, windows-rt

I need to compress file for send in HttpWebRequest for a server. I try to use external classes of C# but doesn't work in Universal Apps. I try this with a original classes that can I use in Universal apps and this is my code:

```
 //SycroZipFile and UploadFile are StorageFile type.
 using (Stream writeStream = await SyncroZipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
 {
     using (Stream readStream = await UploadFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
     {
         await readStream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
     }
 }
```

But the ZipFile is corrupt and doesn't work, any one can help me for compress file in Windows Phone Universal Apps? Thanks a lot, sorry for my english and Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to flush the write stream before closing it. `writeStream.Flush();`

Comment: The using destroy this stream when using finally the code apply stream.flush() and stream.close()! Thanks :D

Comment: `using` indeed closes the stream but does not (always) flush it! Sometimes an explicit call to `Flush()` is needed... But see that you already solved it. Always good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve my problem! If you are programmer of Windows Phone Universal Apps have a problems with a external classes to zip a files, you can use my code with original classes from Visual that can use in Universal Apps:

```
//The UploadFile and SyncroZipFile are StorageFile's.
using (Stream StreamToUploadFile = await UploadFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    using (Stream StreamToSyncroZipFile = await SyncroZipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        using (ZipArchive UploadFileCompressed = new ZipArchive(StreamToSyncroZipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry NewZipEntry = UploadFileCompressed.CreateEntry(UploadFileName);

            using (Stream SWriter = NewZipEntry.Open())
            {
                 await StreamToUploadFile.CopyToAsync(SWriter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code work perfectly for my, and finally my ZipArchive it's not corrupt and I can open it! Good Luck!